# Enum of strings in C#

Tags: c#, enums

have this class:

```
public static class Command
{
    public const string SET_STB_MEDIA_CTRL = "SET STB MEDIA CTRL ";
    public static string ECHO = "ECHO";
    public static string SET_CHANNEL = "SET CHANNEL ";
    public static string GET_VOLUMN = "GET VOLUMN";
    public static string GET_MAX_VOLUMN = "GET MAX VOLUMN ";
    public string SET_STB_MEDIA_LIST = "SET STB MEDIA LIST ";
}
```

then:

```
public static class MultimediaConstants
{
    public const string VIDEO = "video";
    public const string AUDIO = "audio";
    public const string PHOTO = "photo";
    public const string ALL = "all";
    public const string BACKGROUND_MUSIC = "background_music";
    public const string TV = "tv";
    public const string ACTION_PLAY = "play";
}
```

point is, that I would like to have something like this:

```
public static string SET_STB_MEDIA_CTRL (MultimediaConstants type,  MultimediaConstants action)
{
    return Command.SET_STB_MEDIA_CTRL + "type:" + type + "action:" + action;
}
```

So the result of this method should be:

```
 SET STB MEDIA CTRL type:tv action:play
```

The call of the method will be:

```
 SET_STB_MEDIA_CTRL (MultimediaConstants.TV, MultimediaConstants.ACTION_PLAY);
```

Comment: you can't ask for an instance of a static class as method argument because you can't create instance of a static class

Comment: These arent enums. these are classes. you can create an enum using the `enum` keyword instead of class. then you can use the values like you want.

Comment: @Sehnsucht  That's why he want's an `Enum of strings`, like java lets you do

Comment: @SamIam I understood ; I just explained why it's not possible

Comment: @RichardBarker They're conceptually enums.  It's an appropriate use of the term in a general CS sense.  C#'s implementation of enums isn't capable of accomplishing this, however.  That makes these not C# enums, but calling them enums in a general sense is still applicable.

Comment: yes methods cannot be applied to enums. to however i feel that's bad practice. But that's probably just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to approach problems like this is for the class in question to have a private constructor, and to have public static field/properties that are initialized with values of that instance.  This is a way of having a fixed finite number of immutable instances of that type, while still allowing methods to accept parameters of that type.

The following code is valid C# 6.0.

```
public class Command
{
    private Command(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public static Command SET_STB_MEDIA_CTRL { get; } = new Command("SET STB MEDIA CTRL ");
    public static Command ECHO { get; } = new Command("ECHO");
    public static Command SET_CHANNEL { get; } = new Command("SET CHANNEL ");
    public static Command GET_VOLUMN { get; } = new Command("GET VOLUMN");
    public static Command GET_MAX_VOLUMN { get; } = new Command("GET MAX VOLUMN ");
    public static Command SET_STB_MEDIA_LIST { get; } = new Command("SET STB MEDIA LIST ");
}
```

Comment: don't forget to make them readonly!

Comment: @DanielA.White, since they're getter-only properties, they're automagically readonly

Comment: ah didn't notice that this was c# 6

Comment: @Servy thanks, works perfect!!